# Are there any limitations or performance impacts on materialized views in Oracle 12cR1 standard edition versus the enterprise edition?

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, database-administration

We are facing slowness in performance of materialized views (complete) refresh in Oracle 12.1.0.2 Standard edition.

Hence, I would like to know if there are any limitations imitations or performance impacts on materialized views in Oracle 12cR1 standard edition versus the enterprise edition?

Is switching from the standard edition to the enterprise the only solution to improve the performance?

P.S: I am unable to find the options to improve performance in standard edition.

Comment: Regardless of version, a complete refresh will impact performance. Adjust the interval between updates and the approach (each N minutes? on commit? fast refresh?) accordingh to the volume of data. Having CLOB columns also impacts performance

Comment: @Alfabravo ,yes i agree that complete refresh impact the performance.Also i wanted to know if there are any limitations on mviews in standard edition compared to enterprise edition.

Comment: Nope. AFAIK, there are no changes on that matter between those versions.

Answer (score 0):

Standard edition does not have any direct limitations that affect the performance a of materialized view complete refresh.  However, Standard Edition does not support partitioning and parallelism, two features which are frequently used to significantly improve materialized view performance.

If the materialized view refresh SQL is optimal, and there's no way to make Oracle work smarter, you can at least use parallelism to make it work harder.  There are many case where parallelism can improve performance by orders of magnitude, but it depends on a lot of factors.  You need to have Enterprise Edition, decent hardware, a sane configuration, etc.

Even with all that, there are some issues with parallelism and materialized views.  Last time I used it, it worked fine for the SELECT part of a refresh, but it wasn't using direct-path and parallelism for the INSERT part.  Hopefully that's a bug that's been fixed by now.  But you should definitely try it out before committing to purchasing anything.

I'd suggest installing an Enterprise Edition instance only for testing.  Read the OTN Developer License, make sure you're only using it for evaluation, and follow the other rules.  I'm not a lawyer and can't promise anything, but it appears the intent of the developer license was specifically to allow you to test things like this for free.

(The only limitation mentioned in the [Oracle Database Editions](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/DBLIC/editions.htm#DBLIC109) comparison table is that only Enterprise Edition supports materialized view rewrite.  But that probably doesn't affect a materialized view complete refresh, unless that refresh benefits from another materialized view.  Materialized view logs are not always available, which means fast refresh is not always possible, but that only affects Express Edition as far as I can tell.)